# I want to know what this sentence means

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Sometimes it’s as simple as switching where and how you sit that can
>   set the tone for the rest of your day.

Does it mean... - something like :

> A Simple action that how and where you sit can set the tone for the rest
>   of your day.
>
> As simple an action as swiching how and where you sit can set the tone
>   for the rest of your day.

This?

I thought `"it"` meant something before that sentence 
And `as simple as` was `Comparison with something`.

But If I think like that .. this setence dosn't make sense in the News paper.

Thank you for reading ! I wait for your comment :>

[image]

Comment: Yes, **as simple an action as switching [etc.]**. I say that to explain this to you. But keep in mind that in English, we don't need the word **action** because **switching** is an action (verb). :)

Comment: Thank you Lambie ! :> I got it now

Comment: Ah, it's no nice when getting it is as simple as reading a decent answer. :)

Comment: Oh I got you wrong because of " It's no nice " :) Thank you so much again !
If you meant " it is no nice " ... I am sorry ..! my comment was too short maybe ?

Comment: Whoops: It's so nice. :)

Comment: :>> Lambie Could I ask one more ?

you said :

Ah, it's so nice when getting it is as simple as reading a decent answer. :)

It means It is so nice when I get it simply by reading your answer ?

Actually I thought I got it haha but on seeing your "as simple as" I am being confused again :P what a stupid .. !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic expression is: to be as [adjective: easy or simple] as + verbING + object

- to be as simple as counting to ten
- to be as easy as reading the book

This idiom can be restated as: **It is not more difficult than** counting to ten or reading the book.

in the question: It is not more difficult than switching where and how you sit for you to set the tone for the rest of your day.

To set the tone is another idiom. It means: to have a quality that defines your day.

So, if you switch where you sit that is a simple solution to improving your entire day.

Comment: Oh thank you so much for comment again :>>
you are trying to help my understanding with your best !! 
I got it 70% now ( It is a lot of progress haha thx )

Answer (score -2):

It is worth nothing that the original example sentence

> Sometimes it’s as simple as switching where and how you sit that can set the tone for the rest of your day.

is grammatically incorrect. The two clauses "switching where and how you sit" and "that can set the tone for the rest of your day" do not combine properly in this construction. The sentence could be recast as

> - Sometimes to set the tone for the rest of your day is as simple as switching where and how you sit.
> - Sometimes it can be as simple as switching where and how you sit to set the tone for the rest of your day.

There are various other ways these ideas could be expressed. Since, judging by the source, the example is unrehearsed dialog, it is not too surprising that in forming a somewhat complicated sentence the speaker got slightly confused.  However, a fluent speaker should have no problem understanding the intended meaning here, and there is no real ambiguity. Which only goes to show that strict grammatical correctness is not always vital to correct understanding, although it generally helps.

In short, the original sentence means that the tone for the remainder of the day can (sometimes) be set (or changed) by a simple action such as changing the choice of seat or changing how one sits. Note that the original did not say this would change the tone for the better, although that might well be how a listener takes it. The speaker suggests that simple actions can set a tone, for better or worse.

"While "as simple as" does mean "no more difficult than" it has a significantly different implication. "as simple as" emphasizes that the task or operation is very simple indeed. One might write:

> To get Congress to agree on such a measure would be no more difficult than herding cats or building a stairway to the moon.

That does not imply that the task is simple, indeed it implies that it is so hard as to be impossible. If one wrote

> To get Congress to agree on such a measure would be as simple as explaining the reasons for it.

the implications are very different indeed. That suggests that the task is easily achieved.

In the idiom "as simple as" "simple" conveys both "not hard" and "not complex". Some uses will emphasize one of these to a greater degree, some the other. Something can be "simple" in the sense of not being at all complex, but  be very hard to achieve. One would not use "as simple as" to describe such a situation, unless perhaps the idiom is used in an ironic sense.

For example:

> Solving the problem of global warming is as simple as building a perpetual motion machine.

Since it is theoretically impossible to build such a machine, this is not a truly "simple" solution.

Comment: Oh Thank you David !! wow ... I am impressed by your decent answer..!.
Actually to understand I review your comment again and again.
but when I face "as simple as" it reminds me its usage - For example :

*Making Cookie is as simple as drinking a cup of water.
( something like .. A is simple like B )


Sometimes to set the tone for the rest of your day is as simple as switching where and how you sit

When I see this sentence that you made for me

Comment: When I see this sentence that you made for me~

I feel like ... it is saying just a comparison about how much It is a simple action.
but you said " the original sentence means that the tone for the remainder of the day can (sometimes) be set (or changed) by a simple action such as changing the choice of seat or changing how one sits ".

It is not just about comparison but about suggest as you said.

Maybe .. I know only usage of " as soon as " as a comparison.

Comment: so .. [Sometimes to set the tone for the rest of your day is as simple as switching where and how you sit] this sentence can't be recast as [sometimes to set the tone for the rest of your day is as simple as making cookie] like this.